# Wait for something in node.js

Tags: node.js, cheerio

I'm trying to make a webscraper, but I can't get my function to wait for the second request to fill the name key on my object. It always return undefined.

```
const request = require('request');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const base_url = 'https://www.supremenewyork.com';
const shop_url = 'https://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/';

function getItems(category) {
    var items = [];
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        request.get(shop_url + category, function(err, res, body) {
            if(err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                var $ = cheerio.load(body);
                $('a', '.inner-article').each(function(i, el) {
                    var url = base_url + $(this).attr('href');
                    var isSoldout = false;
                    var name;
                    if($(this).find('div').attr('class', 'sold_out_tag').length === 1)
                        isSoldout = true;
                    request.get(url, function(err, res, html) {
                        var $ = cheerio.load(html);
                        name = $('h1', 'div').text();
                    })
                    items.push({name: name, url: url, isSoldout: isSoldout});
                })
                resolve(items);
            }
        })
    })
}
```

I expect the name key to be fill but no, i get undefined

Comment: You're pushing to the array *outside* the callback where the values are...

Comment: @jonrsharpe should i put the push _inside_ the request.get ? If I do that I don't get anything

Comment: it won't push anything inside

Comment: Is this for pre-ES6? I think you're probably following an old tutorial

Comment: @pguardiario i've done it by myself, i'm not following any special tutorial

Comment: You should consider switching to async/await and following a modern tutorial. Nobody wants to answer your question because it's too messy.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `request-promise` package which wraps `request` in `Promise`. Then you can use `async/await` to wait for result like:

```
const rp = require('request-promise');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const base_url = 'https://www.supremenewyork.com';
const shop_url = 'https://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/';

// notice async keyword
async function getItems(category) {
  var items = [];
  try {
    // using await to wait for promise to resolve
    const body = await rp.get(shop_url + category)
    var $ = cheerio.load(body);
    $('a', '.inner-article').each(function(i, el) {
      var url = base_url + $(this).attr('href');
      var isSoldout = false;
      var name;
      if($(this).find('div').attr('class', 'sold_out_tag').length === 1)
        isSoldout = true;
      try {
        const html = await rp.get(url)
        var $ = cheerio.load(html);
        name = $('h1', 'div').text();
        items.push({name: name, url: url, isSoldout: isSoldout});
      } catch (err) {
        throw err;
      }
    })
  } catch (e) {
    throw e;
  }
  return items;
}
```

More about `async/await` at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)